# Javascript serving a file for download

Tags: javascript, base64, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a file in memory for user to download, not through server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server)

First of, this is client side JavaScript. And I know JavaScript is not designed for this.

in a specific piece of code, I have a file name, and the data encoded in base64. This information is already client side, accessible through JavaScript. Does anyone know a way to decode it and serve it to the user as a file using a download dialogue? I know a function from the Apache commons to decode base64, but I don't know if it would be compatible with any ideas you might have.

Thank you for your help.

PS: I can't use HTML 5. The code must work in IE8 and up.